# Is it possible to use “next” between subject and verb?

Tags: adverbs, adverbial-phrases, perfect-aspect, future-perfect, subject-pronouns

> When **we next see** Alex and Max, who are presently parents of two
> children, they will have had a new baby in their family.

Source: *English Grammar Digest* by Trudy Aronson.

I know Only a few adverbs of time (recently, finally, eventually and previously) can be placed in this structure: **Subject + Adverb of time + main verb + object.**
So, this sentence seems odd to me!

Comment: Yes. An adverb can almost go anywhere in a clause (e.g., Next when we see Alex and Max, they will...; When next we see Alex and Max, they will...; When we next see Alex and Max, they will...; When we see next Alex and Max, they will...; When we see Alex and Max next, they will...). Granted, a couple of those come off as rather stilted, but they're not ungrammatical and the meaning remains the same in all of them since the "see" is all "next" can modify. The only places in that entire clause where "next" would change the meaning is within the subject "Alex and Max" (e.g., "Alex and next Max").

Comment: @BenjaminHarman That looks like it should be an answer, not a comment.